# How set bold for docx run apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

How set bold for run with run.getCTR().getRPr()?
I write this code but it doesn't work at all.

```
run.setBold(true);
```

I had the same problem with font-size but I fixed it with this code:

```
CTHpsMeasure size = CTHpsMeasure.Factory.newInstance();
sizeFa.setVal(new BigInteger((sizePoint * 2) + ""));
run.getCTR().getRPr().setSz(size);
run.getCTR().getRPr().setSzCs(size);
```

Now I want to set bold with code like above, with getCTR(). what should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `run.getCTR().getRPr().setSzCs(size);` is needed for you to set the font size, then you are using `Complex Script` (`Cs`) characters. That might be characters of special bidirectional (right to left) language (arabic for example).

So for bold you should try using [CTRPr.setBCs](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTRPr.java#CTRPr.setBCs%28org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTOnOff%29).

```
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTOnOff;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff;
...
  run.setBold(true);
  CTOnOff ctonoff = CTOnOff.Factory.newInstance();
  ctonoff.setVal(STOnOff.ON);
  run.getCTR().getRPr().setBCs(ctonoff);
...
```

Comment: You are right, I'm using Complex Characters.Thank you. @Axel Richter