# Apache POI XWPFRun isBold does not detect bold

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a doxc document that has some bold text. For some reason run.isBold() is returnign false although the run itsel is in bold. What might be the issue here?

The code i am useing to read the file:

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);
        for(XWPFParagraph paragraphs: document.getParagraphs()){

            for(XWPFRun run: paragraphs.getRuns()){
                System.out.println(run.isBold());

                System.out.println(run.text());
        }
```

File content looks like this:

2. **Mõisted**

   2.1.   Some text

   2.1.1. **Pooled** – some text

Weird is it gets that the title (**HANKELEPINGU ÜLDTINGIMUSED**) at the beginnign of the file is bold, but after that nothing is bold.

Comment: What `apache poi` version used? Also this might not be answerable without having a sample `*.docx` file where the problem occurs. [XWPFRun.isBold](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#isBold--) states: "Whether ... bold property shall be applied to all non-complex script characters ... of this run...". So if complex script characters are used (arab, hebrew, asian, ...), this cannot work at all. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380259/how-set-bold-for-docx-run-apache-poi/46380564#46380564 for an example to **set** bold in complex script.

Comment: Im using APache POI 3.17

Comment: Can you upload the `*.docx` file having this content somewhere? But please check whether that file then still has the problem.

Comment: I uploaded part of the file. Cant upload entirety of it. But this small part has the same issue https://ufile.io/5jq4l

Comment: The text "Üldosa" and "Mõisted" are not bold because they was formatted bold but because the whole paragraph is in style "Heading2". And the text "Pooled" also is not formatted bold but the special character style "Paks" is applied. So someone has used `Word` [Styles](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-styles-f8b96097-4d25-4fac-8200-6139c8093109) extensively. Not bad at all. But unfortunatelly `apache poi` not takes much care about styles until now. And doing this our selfs using the underlying low level classes will really be much expensive.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction where can i see what style is used where and then manually place the styles or whatever. This wont go into development for quite a while, but the client wants an time estimate. so im trying to get some quick ideawhat needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I inspected your `test.docx` file I can tell you the following:

The text "Üldosa" and "Mõisted" are not bold because they was formatted bold but because the whole paragraph is in style "Heading2". And the text "Pooled" also is not formatted bold but the special character style "Paks" is applied. So someone has used Word [Styles](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-styles-f8b96097-4d25-4fac-8200-6139c8093109) extensively. Not bad at all. Just as HTML should rather be formatted using CSS style sheets rather than directly, in Word also using style should be preferred. But of course also the problems while parsing are the same. Without additional parsing the style sheets one cannot determine how the text shall be presented. Unfortunately `apache poi` not takes much care about styles until now.

How can one come to that insight? A `*.docx` file is simply a `ZIP` archive. So we can unzip it and will find:

`/word/document.xml`:

```
<w:r ...>
 <w:rPr>
  ...
  <w:b/>
  ...
 </w:rPr>
 <w:t>HANKELEPINGU ÜLDTINGIMUSED</w:t>
</w:r>
```

This is a text run really formatted bold directly.

But

```
<w:p ...>
 <w:pPr>
  <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2"/>
  <w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0"/><w:numId w:val="2"/></w:numPr> 
  ...
 </w:pPr>
 <w:r ...>
  <w:t>Üldosa</w:t>
 </w:r>
</w:p>
```

this is a paragraph having style "Heading2" and is automatic numbered.

So why is that text bold? In `/word/styles.xml` we find:

```
<w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Heading2">
 <w:name w:val="heading 2"/>
 <w:basedOn w:val="Normal"/>
 ...
 <w:link w:val="Heading2Char"/>
 ...
</w:style>
```

This is the paragraph style "Heading2" which links to the character style "Heading2Char".

```
<w:style w:type="character" w:customStyle="1" w:styleId="Heading2Char">
 <w:name w:val="Heading 2 Char"/>
 ...
 <w:link w:val="Heading2"/>
 ...
 <w:rPr>
  ...
  <w:b/>
  ...
 </w:rPr>
</w:style>
```

This is the character style "Heading2Char" which is set bold.

To answer the question how to proceed this using `apache poi` one must know that `apache poi` `XWPF` bases on the `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*` classes which comes from `ooxml-schemas.*.jar`. So we need information about this. Unfortunately there is not any `API` documentation public available. So we need downloading the sources and doing `javadoc` our self.

So what to do next? Iterating over paragraphs and runs as you done already. But additional for each paragraph try to get the style for this paragraph. If there is one, get it and it's character style and check what settings it provides. Also for each run try to get the character style for this run. If there is one, get it and check what settings it provides.

The following code is doing this, but only to check whether the style provides bold setting. So it is really not complete and making it complete will really be much expensive.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

public class ReadWordHavingStyles {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("test.docx"));

  XWPFStyles styles = document.getStyles();
  XWPFStyle style = null;
  boolean isPBold = false;
  boolean isRBold = false;
  String boldReasonP = "";
  String boldReasonR = "";
  CTRPr cTRPr = null;

  for(XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
   isPBold = false;
   boldReasonP = "";
   String pStyleId = paragraph.getStyleID();
   if (pStyleId != null) {
    style = styles.getStyle(pStyleId);
    if (style != null) {
     String linkStyleId = style.getLinkStyleID();
     style = styles.getStyle(linkStyleId);
     if (style != null) {
      cTRPr = style.getCTStyle().getRPr();
      if (cTRPr != null) {
       if (!cTRPr.isSetB()) {
        isPBold = false;
       } else {
        STOnOff.Enum val = cTRPr.getB().getVal();
        isPBold = !((STOnOff.FALSE == val) || (STOnOff.X_0 == val) || (STOnOff.OFF == val));
       }
      }
      boldReasonP = " whole P is " + ((isPBold)?"":"not ") + "bold because of style " + linkStyleId;
     }
    }
   }

   if (!isPBold) boldReasonP = " P is not bold";

   for(XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()){
    isRBold = isPBold;
    boldReasonR = "";
    cTRPr = run.getCTR().getRPr();
    if (cTRPr != null) {
     CTString rStyle = cTRPr.getRStyle();
     if (rStyle != null) {
      String rStyleId = rStyle.getVal();
      style = styles.getStyle(rStyleId);
      if (style != null) {
       cTRPr = style.getCTStyle().getRPr();
       if (cTRPr != null) {
        if (!cTRPr.isSetB()) {
         isRBold = false;
        } else {
         STOnOff.Enum val = cTRPr.getB().getVal();
         isRBold = !((STOnOff.FALSE == val) || (STOnOff.X_0 == val) || (STOnOff.OFF == val));
        }      
       }
       boldReasonR = " run is " + ((isRBold)?"":"not ") + "bold because of style " + rStyleId;
      }
     }
    }

    if (!isRBold) boldReasonR = " run is not bold";

    cTRPr = run.getCTR().getRPr();
    if (cTRPr != null) {
     if (cTRPr.isSetB()) {
      STOnOff.Enum val = cTRPr.getB().getVal();
      isRBold = !((STOnOff.FALSE == val) || (STOnOff.X_0 == val) || (STOnOff.OFF == val));
      boldReasonR = " run is " + ((isRBold)?"":"not ") + "bold because of direct formatting";
     }      
    }

    System.out.println(run.text() + " isBold:" + isRBold + ":" + boldReasonP + boldReasonR);

   }
  }

  document.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Well luckly for me bold and numbering are the most important parts as of yet. Thank you, i can now see what must be done to do what the client needs and i can finish the analysis.