# How identify a word bold in paragraph in word file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I read a Word file using [NPOI](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi) library. I need to identify which words are bold.

Consider the following paragraph, for example.

John is a student at **Dalhousie** University in **Canada**.

Answers: Dalhousie, Canada

I can read a paragraph like this.

```
string text = document.Paragraphs[i].Text;
```

Now I do not know with what function I can check which words are bold.

I do not want to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word library. But if you can suggest another library, no problem.

Comment: Have you seen [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54516225/apache-poi-xwpfrun-isbold-does-not-detect-bold)?

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot. We can use it this way: 

 var a = document.Paragraphs[i].Runs; 

var b = a[j].IsBold;